# Nested usage of interfaces?

Tags: solidity, interfaces

Using solidity ^4.x, it seems I can use an interface as a parameter type in a function from a different interface.

Example:

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transfer() external;
}
```

```
import "./IERC20.sol";

interface InterfaceB {
    function myOtherFunc(IERC20 tokenAddress) external;
}
```

Is this good practice? Are there any examples of successful protocols or dapps using this pattern?

Comment: `Using solidity 0.5.10, it seems I can use an interface as a parameter type in a function from a different interface` - also true in Solc 0.4.x. `Is this good practice?` - depending on your use-case. `Are there any examples of successful protocols or dapps using this pattern` - this pattern is general, and not related to anything specific about Ethereum. You can find it in many other systems, implemented in many other languages.